# Can't get templates to work in Django

Tags: django

I'm following this tutorial (http://lightbird.net/dbe/cal1.html) to build a calendar app, but I can't get the templates to work correctly.

I made a directory named `cal` in `project/templates` and copied `base.html` there. Then I extended the template `cal/main.html` with the following:

```
{% extends "cal/base.html" %}
<!-- ... -->

<a href="{% url cal.views.main year|add:'-3' %}">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
<a href="{% url cal.views.main year|add:'3' %}">Next &gt;&gt;</a>

    {% for year, months in years %}
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <h4>{{ year }}</h4>
        {% for month in months %}
            <div class=
            {% if month.current %}"current"{% endif %}
            {% if not month.current %}"month"{% endif %} >
                {% if month.entry %}<b>{% endif %}
                <a href="{% url cal.views.month year month.n %}">{{ month.name }}</a>
                {% if month.entry %}</b>{% endif %}
            </div>

            {% if month.n == 6 %}<br />{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

In my `project/urls.py` I have the following configuration:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^cal/', include('cal.urls')),                                         
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

In `cal/urls.py` I have the following configuration:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from cal.views import main

urlpatterns = patterns('cal.views',
    (r'^(\d+)/$', main),
    (r'', main),
)
```

I'm not sure where I went wrong. All that is showing up right now when I run the app is a blank screen with a "Home" button on the top left corner that takes me to the admin page. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base.html you must have something like that:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

And in main.html:

```
{% extends "cal/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<a href="{% url cal.views.main year|add:'-3' %}">&lt;&lt; Prev</a>
<a href="{% url cal.views.main year|add:'3' %}">Next &gt;&gt;</a>

{% for year, months in years %}
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <h4>{{ year }}</h4>
    {% for month in months %}
        <div class=
        {% if month.current %}"current"{% endif %}
        {% if not month.current %}"month"{% endif %} >
            {% if month.entry %}<b>{% endif %}
            <a href="{% url cal.views.month year month.n %}">{{ month.name }}</a>
            {% if month.entry %}</b>{% endif %}
        </div>

        {% if month.n == 6 %}<br />{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```